# Why MySQL mariadb rollback data without reason?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, commit

After many use of MySQL servers in different hardware like laptops with Windows os, in very rare case the data is rollback to previous transactions. The algorithm is working fine in general in thousand of transactions with different clients but something happen in 0.01% of case when close the application and release memory  the data of last 4 or 10 transaction is rollback. The application is desktop and was develop using .net and MySQL library and mariadb 10.2 free edition in localhost station. There is a retry if commit fail. Is it possible that some transaction save data partially after an error and transaction no closed well ?? What are reason for fail commit???, or maybe hard disk fail,  or windows issue. ??. 
If report the data is showed so commit is working but in those case when close application data is rollback ??? Why ???
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would insert a logging action in the code itself to first report any errors in the commit and retry, this even if it succeed. This will create a pattern that will not show if your problem happens . The logging action shows contain information to help you determine why , when and for what user, for what OS and computer it all happens

Comment: I had seen a similar problem hen using a COM module. When the module was not correctly released, there was a high probability that the file it worked with was incomplete *(not saved completely)*. It was in the wrong use. The application failed to call "Close" *(Dispose in C# terminology)* function. This was caused for incorrect application ending *(e.g. when user pressed the "X" (close) button when work was in progress)*. This is a hard to track problem, but try to search all "exit paths" to check correct dispose of all modules.

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons for seemingly-random `ROLLBACKs`.

Check for errors after every statement in the transaction, and after the `COMMIT`.  (Errors on Commit probably occur only for Galera-based clustering and Group Replication.  But test anyway.)

When an error occurs, try to capture `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS;`.  Turn on `innodb_print_all_deadlocks`, then look in the log.

Meanwhile, can you describe the transaction?  Better yet, show us the SQL involved.

Comment: The commit it is done by ADO.Net mysql library inside dispose function. Transaction object is created inside  a using statement.
When using end, dispose is calling. Commit depend of automatic call dispose by the .net engine.
If commit throw exception no explicit rollback or close connection exist . I don't now if this can cause problems or by default rollback is done on commit fail exception.
  The ADO.Net is an old version of official release. Can  be this the problem ?